# How to get URL array parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the URL array parameter from javascript 
i have an array for example `http://localhost/search?&p[]=599` and i need to receive the 599 in javascript.I use the below function to get the parameter which is not array.How to get an array parameter. ?

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an array. It is just a name with `[]` in it.

It is almost as simple as passing it the name of the thing you want `"p[]"` but `[` and `]` have special meaning in a regular expression so you need to escape them.

Regex escape characters have special meaning in JavaScript string literals, so you need to escape them too.

```
getURLParameter("p\\[\\]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Some characters, like `[`, have special meaning in regular expressions, so you must escape them:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (
            RegExp(
              name.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\\|]/g, '\\$&')
              + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)'
            ).exec(location.search) || [,null]
        )[1]
    );
}
```

Also see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)